# regular expression without word match

Tags: c#, regex

I have this expression:

```
-a bp cd 4 -6 3 -n sig3 -p 0.5 0.7
```

I want to match all from `-a` to `-n`. This means that the prefix and suffix are: `-` with one letter.

I have a start with:`(?<=-a )(?<ida>[^-]*)`

But i need to exclude also the letter.

Note that the -n can be any other letter with - before it and know at run time only.

How should I do that? 
Thanks to all the Answers, i finally cracked it: 
(?<=-a )(?.*?(?=-[a-z]|$))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your regex did not fully showed up before the edit because it contains angular brackets. To avoid this in your future postings, add the "backward tick" characters around the text that you want formatted as a code snippet. You can also skip `<br>`s in the markup, because the editor lets you insert newline characters directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your pattern is:

- '-a' followed by
- anything that is not a dash `[^-]` or a dash followed by a character that is not a letter `-[^a-z]` repeated one or more times, followed by
- a dash and a letter `-[a-z]`

This regex should do it:

```
(?<=-a)([^-]|-[^a-z])+(?=-[a-z])
```

Comment: thanks, it helped me to get to what i want:(?<=-a )(?<ida>.*?(?=-[a-z]|$))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
(?<=-a )(?>[^ ]+| (?!-n))*(?= -n)
```

The interest of this expression is to avoid lazy quantifiers and to trim spaces at the begining and at the end.

Details:

```
(?<=-a )          # preceded by `-a `
(?>               # open an atomic group (non-capturing)
    [^ ]+         # all that is not a space
  |               # or
    [ ](?!-n)     # a space not followed by `-n`
)*                # repeat the group zero or more times
(?= -n)           # check if ` -n` follows
```